# Why does 'The electron density builds quadratically with distance from the nuclues.'?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, orbitals

I found the statement above on this useful website.
http://photonicswiki.org/index.php?title=Atomic_Orbitals_and_Nodes

But I am confused. Why would that be the case? Is this based on some exotic theory or is there an obvious reason?
thanks

Comment: It is the volume of a thin shell with fixed thickness that increases as the square of the distance.

Comment: As in the article there is no mathematical definition of electron density, I would be suspisious  of taking it as  correct just with plots. Charge density is associated with the probability distribuition, i.e. the orbitals. , there should be a mathematical derivation of the statement which is not there and no reference is given.

Comment: @Pieter That seems more like an answer than like a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Speculation:**

the term "density" has a sense of "orbital density."

When **all** the orbits are filled ( 1S2, 2S2, 1p6, ....) than the probability $\mid \psi(r) \mid^2$ to find an electron at radius $r$ is rising quadratically.

It needs a proof - I dont have it. But it seems to me possible: if the volume density of electrons is constant - the number of electrons in a the volume $S(r) dr$ (where $S(r)$ is a sphere at radius $r$)  rises quadratically with $r$, since $ S(r) \sim r^2$.

[image]

1. In that sense the **red** curve *might* describe the number of electron possitions at distance $r$ that can be occupied.
2. The **blue** curve *resembles* a distribution of electrons at some temperature $T$ (again, I dont have an experience to say that it really works like that also for electron orbitals.).

Answer (score -2):

It is not an "electron density" since the electron is [point-like](https://vladimirkalitvianski.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/zoom-in-atom-or-unknown-physics-of-short-distances/).